# Including session variable into stripe payment php

Tags: php, concatenation, session-variables

very simple thing but i'm trying to include this:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['totalprice']; ?>
```

Into the amount field of charge.php which is this:

```
<?php
  require_once('config.php');

  $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];

  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      'email' => 'customer@example.com',
      'card'  => $token
  ));

  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => "".$_SESSION['totalprice']."",
      'currency' => 'eur'
  ));

  echo '<h1>Successfully charged $50.00!</h1>';
?>
```

I think it's a problem of indentation but can't get a way around it. This is the error:

> *Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest' with message 'Invalid integer: ' in
> /home/barceloneta/public_html/stripe-php-3.2.0/lib/ApiRequestor.php:98
> from API request 'req_6ycxcj8LmrLt9T' Stack trace: #0
> /home/barceloneta/public_html/stripe-php-3.2.0/lib/ApiRequestor.php(210):
> Stripe\ApiRequestor->handleApiError('{\n "error": {\n...', 400, Array,
> Array) #1
> /home/barceloneta/public_html/stripe-php-3.2.0/lib/ApiRequestor.php(60):
> Stripe\ApiRequestor->_interpretResponse('{\n "error": {\n...', 400,
> Array) #2
> /home/barceloneta/public_html/stripe-php-3.2.0/lib/ApiResource.php(105):
> Stripe\ApiRequestor->request('post', '/v1/charges', Array, Array) #3
> /home/barceloneta/public_html/stripe-php-3.2.0/lib/ApiResource.php(137):
> Stripe\ApiResource::_staticRequest('post', '/v1/charges', Array, NULL)
>
> ## 4 /home/barceloneta/public_html/stripe-php-3.2.0/lib/Charge.php(37): Stripe\ApiResource::_create(Array, NULL) #5
>
> /home/barceloneta/public_html/charge.php(15):
> Stripe\Charge::create(Array) #6 /home/barceloneta/public_htm in
> /home/barceloneta/public_html/stripe-php-3.2.0/lib/ApiRequestor.php on
> line 98*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrapping the amount in quotes, making it a string type. It seems that Stripe is pretty strict about that, so remove the quotes and make sure you are sending an integer.

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    'customer' => $customer->id,
    'amount'   => (int) $_SESSION['totalprice'],
    'currency' => 'eur'
));
```

Also, make sure the session key is set and has an integer value before sending it to stripe.